# Firebase push notifications not working when internet connectivity is switched from off to on

Tags: android, firebase

when I send notifications to users having no connectivity  at that particular instant (when i send the notification) and then user turns their mobile data ON ,no notification is received on the user end. I will provide code if necessary.
Any suggestions would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. The main goal is in that, that your message will be sent several times by firebase, by default send period is 4 weeks, untill your notification will arrive. That's from documentation. Hope, my answer was helpful

Comment: Someone answered my question a week ago, I don't know why he deleted it.  If I am not wrong time to live or ttl was my answer.